# Add recursive dependencies source code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, external

I am trying to add some external dependencies, source code to my project so that I can modify anything I want. I tried to add these sources manually, but it takes a lot of time, especially when there is a sort of recursivity in the dependencies.

I was wondering if there is any possibility to add these dependencies source code automatically in Android Studio?

Comment: Do you use gradle or maven?

Comment: I am using gradle